# In Emacs: how to reference latex equation in text by its number .dvi?

Tags: emacs, latex, equation

Suppose, I use Emacs to write a function in latex:

```
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:myeq} 
x=2y
\end{equation}
```

that gives me

```
 x = 2y   (1)
```

in a resulting .dvi.  And suppose I have dozens of such equations.  **Here is the problem:** if I have to reference this equation but don't remember its name I want to be able to reference it by it's number (`(1)` in the shown case).

**The story.** Actually, I know there is an emacs package that has such a function.  Like this: I press key combination, the function asks me to enter an equation number and returns it's name, nicely surrounded by `(\ref{` and `})`.  I used it,  but after changing OS on my computer I've lost that Emacs installation. And now I don't remember what was the name of that package I once installed.  Or maybe it was just a function in `.emacs`. Googling by key words gives RefTex, but I didn't found that feature in RefTex.  So if someone uses that incredible package - please tell me its name!

Comment: tex.stacexchage.com might be worth a try. I did find at least one [post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136568/cross-ref-an-equation-using-reftex-auctex-and-cleveref) that looks promising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the following package:
http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/AuxLabel

Make sure to read the `LIMITATIONS` section.

Comment: Yes, this is it, exactly.  Thank you, it saves me a lot of time. By what keywords did you found that?

Comment: I don't remeber exactly. I find it now when googling for `emacs equation number to reference`.